# Get public download URL from uploaded file in firebase storage with Java rest API

Tags: java, rest, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I would like to get the download URL from a file (Blob) upload by firebase-admin sdk for java.

My Code:

```
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("...")
            .build();

        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        StorageClient storage = StorageClient.getInstance(app);

        Bucket bucket = storage.bucket("...");

        Blob blob = bucket.create(...);
```

so, by this code I am able to upload file in firebase storage.
But I dont know how to get the download URL..
I want to get the URL (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...)

But the method blob.getMediaLink()
returns me the URL (https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage...) which is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which does essentially the same thing as the download URLs generated by Firebase client SDKs, using [Blob.signUrl()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html#signUrl-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.SignUrlOption...-).