# Need to get Public URL for files from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with Firebase cloud functions. I have written  function which gets triggered on OnCreate event from Firebase Realtime database. Currently, this function successfully upload PDF document but I want a public URL to that uploaded document so that anybody can access and see the document.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
const os = require("os");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

admin.initializeApp();

  exports.addMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const original = snapshot.val();
        console.log(snapshot);


        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const filePath = "filename.pdf";
        const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));

        var pdf = new PDFDocument({
                                    size: 'A4', 
                                    info: {Title: 'Tile of File', Author: 'Author'}
                            });
            pdf.text('Emergency Incident Report');

        pdf.pipe(
                 // TODO: figure out how / where to store the file
                    fs.createWriteStream( tmpFilePath )
                ).on('finish', function () {
                console.log('PDF closed');

        return bucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
                destination: 'resized-' + path.basename(filePath),

                            }).then((obj)=>{

                                                console.log(obj);
                                                const upFile = obj[0];
                                                return  upFile.getSignedUrl({ action: 'read', expires: '03-17-2025'}).then((urlUp)=>{

                                                                            console.log(urlUp[0]);
                                                                });
                                });

});

pdf.end();


});
```

But this code logs below  error in firebase

```
A Forbidden error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes specified. Identity and Access Management (IAM) API has not been used in project 575455681031 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting **THIS URL**  then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at GaxiosError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/common.js:17:9)
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:72:27)
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I have tried following solutions but nothing works

[Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250/get-download-url-from-file-uploaded-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase)

[Get public download URL from uploaded file in firebase storage with Java rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393462/get-public-download-url-from-uploaded-file-in-firebase-storage-with-java-rest-ap)

**What I am trying to do?**

I'm uploading a document to firebase storage with success after that done Im trying to get Download Url to that document so that I could save URL to firebase

Comment: What's wrong with the first question you linked?  That's the right way to go.

Comment: @DougStevenson its still giving me the same error which you I shown in question

Comment: @DougStevenson and  the updated answer in first question is not much clear in explaination

Comment: The problem is not to do with your code, but instead with a permissions error for the API key you are using to access Cloud Firestore. In the error message, it is asking you to visit the URL and configure the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @samthecodingman I have configured it but still same error